# Determine when touch down happens and then when it is released

Tags: android

I thought my code would work, but I guess not. I'm just trying to get it to read when the phone is touched. An animation will happen while its held. Then I would like it to determine when it is released so the animation will stop. My code looks like this with toasts as fillers until I get it working.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pImage);
        image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        Toast.makeText(PalsPage.this, "Is DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                         break;
                    } 
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                          Toast.makeText(PalsPage.this, "Is UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                          break;
                    }    
                    return false;
                }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting only the "Is DOWN" Toast.
The problem is in the return value.

You have to return `true`for the code to work. 
 otherwise the ACTION_UP event will not come to this view's listener.

Answer (score 1):

you should return true so your image view keeps the events. i imagine your getting the first toast but not the second.